# python, measure unique elements by row ignoring specific values

Tags: python, unique, counting

I have a data frame of 6 columns where each entry has a sequence of numbers.

```
pd.DataFrame(FixByteOrderUnique)
Out[518]: 
         0   1   2    3    4  5
0       58  68  58   59   -1 -1
1       59  69  59   58   -1 -1
2       93  94  93   33   -1 -1
3       58  59  58   68   -1 -1
4       92  94  92   33   -1 -1
5       59  58  59   69   -1 -1
6       57  48  57   79   -1 -1
7       15  26  15  101   -1 -1
```

I want per line to measure the number of unique elements ignoring in the count the numbers: -1,100,101 and 102. Valid numbers are from [0,99].

What I did was to make a lambda function that ignores in the counting the -1

```
def myfunc(row):
    if -1 in row.values:
        return row.nunique() - 1
    else:
        return row.nunique()
```

and then call my function like this

```
pd_sequences['unique'] = pd.DataFrame(FixByteOrderUnique).apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

How I can include inside my lambda function to check if the number is from [0,99] to be eligible for the uniqueness counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `myfunc` to

```py
def myfunc(row):
    return row[(row < 100) & (row > -1)].nunique()
```

using boolean indexing of dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Using `len`, `set` and `filter`:

```
df['nuniq'] = df.apply(lambda a: len(set(filter(lambda x:x in range(100), a))), 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2    3  4  5  nuniq
0  58  68  58   59 -1 -1      3
1  59  69  59   58 -1 -1      3
2  93  94  93   33 -1 -1      3
3  58  59  58   68 -1 -1      3
4  92  94  92   33 -1 -1      3
5  59  58  59   69 -1 -1      3
6  57  48  57   79 -1 -1      3
7  15  26  15  101 -1 -1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to:

```
def myfunc(row):
    return row.drop_duplicates()[0 < row.drop_duplicates() < 100]
```